# How can I get substring from a string in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am trying to extract a specific string from a string in linux.

For example, I want to extract '***android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApplication***' from the below string.

The String has a regular format and only the string within parenthesis is changeable.

```
Join point 'method-execution(boolean android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApplication(android.content.pm.PackageParser$Package, android.content.res.Resources, org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.util.AttributeSet, int, java.lang.String[]))' in Type
```

However, I have a trouble in finding a proper approach to do this.

At first, I tried sed command but it's too complicate so I couldn't complete the work.

Could you recommend any other approach to do this?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like AOP syntax. So with certain assumption, this can be done as :

```
echo "Join point...." | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Explanation : cut based on `(` and get second field, which is the method signature except parameters. Since we are not interested in return type as well, split the signature based on blank space and get the second field, which is the method name.

Answer (score 2):

If the interested string is always the second string after the first `(` then:

```
echo "..." | awk -F '[()]' '{split($2,a," "); printf a[2]}'
```

extract it.

It splits the line using delimiters `(` and `)`. So `$2` will the data between `(` and `)`. `split` splits `$2` and you get the second string which is

```
android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApplication
```

for your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is based your stated invariant, that the substring you're capturing is the only part that varies from file to file, here is a perl solution:

```
Extract=$(perl -ne 'print $1 if /\s*Join point \x27method-execution\(boolean\s+([^(]*)/' file_to_search)
echo $Extract
android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApplication
```

I used the full lead-in because it reduced the chance of false-positive, but if you find other things change and want to use yet a substring of that (e.g., "method-execution(boolean "), that's your choice to make.

This matches out to the where the variant substring starts, which goes to the next invariant--the open parenthesis--so we can just capture while not open parenthesis.  Since it's probably some human interaction changing the variant, I allowed for extra spaces with the \s+ (one or more white space).

You could use almost the same regex with sed, but would need to consume the entire string to avoid it becoming part of the output.  e.g., in shorthand:

```
sed -r 's/.*LEAD_IN(CAPTURE_TEXT).*/\1/
```

Where LEAD_IN is the constant leader, "Join point..." and CAPTURE_TEXT the same capture group as in the perl solution.  Main difference is leading and triling ".*" to consume the entire subject.